# ddply transformation (percentage change) in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have `data.frame` which looks like this:

```
Brand       Year       EUR
Brand1      2015       10
Brand1      2016       20
Brand2      2015       100
Brand2      2016       500
Brand3      2015       25
Brand4      2015       455
...
```

Also, I attach the code below:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

set.seed(1992)
n=68

Year <- sample(c("2015", "2016"), n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
Brand <- sample("Brand", n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)
Brand <- paste0(Brand, sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL))
EUR <- abs(rnorm(n))*100000

df <- data.frame(Year, Brand, EUR)
```

I need some additional data transformations (add more columns) for my future research.

Firstly, I calculate positions for labels (for my future chart) and call it `pos`:

```
df.summary = df %>% group_by(Brand, Year) %>% 
  summarise(EUR = sum(EUR)) %>%   #
  mutate( pos = cumsum(EUR)-0.5*EUR)
```

What I want to do is, to calculate `percentage grow` for each `Brand` in terms of `Year`. So I add this line:

```
df.summary = ddply(df.summary, .(Brand), transform, 
               pChange = (sum(df.summary[df.summary$Year == "2016",]$EUR)/
                         sum(df.summary[df.summary$Year == "2015",]$EUR) )-1  
                     )
```

However, what I get is constant size - growth of all my data frame.

Could you please help me calculating percentage change for each brand?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some expected output? (Actual values of growth.) It'll help verify that we are calculating the right way.

Comment: Probably your problems come from mixing `dplyr` and `plyr`. Did you maybe load `plyr` after `dplyr` and ignore the warnings that print telling you not to do that? It will result in `plyr` functions masking their `dplyr` versions and lead to bugs. Why not just use `dplyr`?

Comment: For example:
    Brand       Year       EUR 
    Brand1     2015      500
    Brand1     2016      1500

So my goal is to get the result: ((1500/500)-1)*100% = 200%
So it means that Brand1 have increased his amount of money in 2016 by 200% compared to 2015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, it would be easier if you use `lag`:

```
df.summary %>% group_by(Brand) %>% 
      mutate(pChange = (EUR - lag(EUR))/lag(EUR) * 100)

# Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
#Groups: Brand [5]
#
#    Brand   Year      EUR      pos   pChange
#   <fctr> <fctr>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1  Brand1   2015 637896.7 318948.3        NA
#2  Brand1   2016 721944.2 998868.8  13.17573
#3  Brand2   2015 708697.6 354348.8        NA
#4  Brand2   2016 300541.1 858968.2 -57.59248
#5  Brand3   2015 454890.1 227445.1        NA
#6  Brand3   2016 576095.6 742937.9  26.64500
#7  Brand4   2015 305712.0 152856.0        NA
#8  Brand4   2016 174073.3 392748.6 -43.05970
#9  Brand5   2015 589970.7 294985.3        NA
#10 Brand5   2016 518510.2 849225.8 -12.11254
```

As suggested by @r2evans, if the `Year` is not arranged beforehand,

```
df.summary %>% group_by(Brand) %>% arrange(Year) %>%
          mutate(pChange = (EUR - lag(EUR))/lag(EUR) * 100)
```

Comment: I suggest you add `arrange(Year)` unless OP is guaranteed that all data is perfectly ordered beforehand. (Also, over to OP if he needs to protect against holes in data, e.g., missing `Year`s.)

Comment: Thank you guys for quick response!

Comment: Is there a way to calculate it without `lag` operator? In other cases I have not numerical variables.

Comment: How do you plan to take a percentage if it is not a numeric variable?

Comment: I have variable not `Year`, but period described in chars.
For example: `Period: {old, new}` and numeric variable `EUR`. In this case, I can't use `lag` operator for variable `Period`.

Comment: So you have something like `{2015, 2016}`?